# Calculating an oauth signature

Tags: rest, post, oauth, hmacsha1, shared-secret

I am trying something a little specific, namely trying to call a REST API. I have been following these [instructions](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth#create_signature_base).

I have been very careful to ensure that I am creating the "Signature base string" correctly. They define it to be created like this:

> (HTTP Method)&(Request URL)&(Normalized Parameters)

You can double check if need be in my code, but I am very sure that it is fine.

The problem that I am having is creating what they call the "oauth signature" and mine isn't matching theirs. They it should be created like this:

> Use the HMAC-SHA1 signature algorithm as defined by the [RFC2104] to sign the request where text is the Signature Base String and key is the concatenated values of the Consumer Secret and Access Secret separated by an '&' character (show '&' even if Access Secret is empty as some methods do not require an Access Token).
>
> The calculated digest octet string, first base64-encoded per [RFC2045], then escaped using the [RFC3986] percent-encoding (%xx) mechanism is the oauth_signature.

I express this in my code like so:

```
var oauthSignature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureBaseString, sharedSecret+"&");
var oauthSignature64 = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(oauthSignature));
console.log("hash in 64: " + oauthSignature64);
```

I am using Google's CryptoJS library. I take the signature base string as the text, I then take my consumer secret as the key concatenated with "&", I have no Access key and it isn't required but that is OK. I then base 64 encode the result of that hash, after which I URI encode it, please could some guys sanity check my understanding of that and my usage/expressing of it in code using this library, I think this is where my problem is.

Here is my full code:

```
var fatSecretRestUrl = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api";

var d = new Date();
var sharedSecret = "xxxx";
var consumerKey = "xxxx";

//this is yet another test tyring to make this thing work
var baseUrl = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?";
var parameters = "method=food.search&oauth_consumer_key="+consumerKey+"&oauth_nonce=123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp="+getTimeInSeconds()+"&oauth_version=1.0&search_expression=banana";
var signatureBaseString = "POST&" + encodeURIComponent(baseUrl) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(parameters);
console.log("signature base string: " + signatureBaseString);
var oauthSignature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureBaseString, sharedSecret+"&");
var oauthSignature64 = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(oauthSignature));
console.log("hash in 64: " + oauthSignature64);

var testUrl = baseUrl+"method=food.search&oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_nonce=123&oauth_signature="+oauthSignature64+"&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp="+getTimeInSeconds()+"&oauth_version=1.0&search_expression=banana";
console.log("final URL: " + testUrl);

var request = $http({
  method :"POST",
  url: testUrl
});
```

I have taken care to ensure that the parameters that I am posting are in lexicographical order and I am very sure that it is correct.

The response that I am getting back is:

> Invalid signature: oauth_signature 'RWeFME4w2Obzn2x50xsXujAs1yI='

So clearly either

1. I haven't understood the instructions provided in the API
2. Or I have understood them but I haven't expressed them in that way in my code
3. Or both of the above
4. Or I have made some subtle mistake somewhere that I can't see

I would really appreciate a sanity check, this has taken a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well...I did it, but not the way that I thought I would end up doing it, I spent hours trying it out with angular then JQuery, then finally I tried Node JS and it worked, here are two working examples, one with `food.get` and another with `foods.search`

**food.get example**

```js
    var rest              = require('restler'),
    crypto            = require('crypto'),
    apiKey           = 'xxxx',
    fatSecretRestUrl = 'http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api',
    sharedSecret     = 'xxxx',
    date             = new Date;
    
    // keys in lexicographical order
    var reqObj = {
      food_id: '2395843', // test query
      method: 'food.get',
      oauth_consumer_key: apiKey,
      oauth_nonce: Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]/, '').substr(2),
      oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000),
      oauth_version: '1.0'
    };
    
    // make the string...got tired of writing that long thing
    var paramsStr = '';
    for (var i in reqObj) {
      paramsStr += "&" + i + "=" + reqObj[i];
    }
    
    // had an extra '&' at the front
    paramsStr = paramsStr.substr(1);
    
    var sigBaseStr = "GET&"
                     + encodeURIComponent(fatSecretRestUrl)
                     + "&"
                     + encodeURIComponent(paramsStr);
    
    // no access token but we still have to append '&' according to the instructions
    sharedSecret += "&";
    
    var hashedBaseStr  = crypto.createHmac('sha1', sharedSecret).update(sigBaseStr).digest('base64');
    
    // Add oauth_signature to the request object
    reqObj.oauth_signature = hashedBaseStr;
    
    rest.get(fatSecretRestUrl, {
      data: reqObj,
    }).on('complete', function(data, response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("DATA: " + data + "\n");
    });
```

**foods.search example**

```js
    var rest              = require('restler'),
    crypto            = require('crypto'),
    apiKey           = 'xxxx',
    fatSecretRestUrl = 'http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api',
    sharedSecret     = 'xxxx',
    date             = new Date;
    
    // keys in lexicographical order
    var reqObj = {
      method: 'foods.search',
      oauth_consumer_key: apiKey,
      oauth_nonce: Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]/, '').substr(2),
      oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000),
      oauth_version: '1.0',
      search_expression: 'mcdonalds' // test query
    };
    
    // make the string...got tired of writing that long thing
    var paramsStr = '';
    for (var i in reqObj) {
      paramsStr += "&" + i + "=" + reqObj[i];
    }
    
    // had an extra '&' at the front
    paramsStr = paramsStr.substr(1);
    
    var sigBaseStr = "POST&"
                     + encodeURIComponent(fatSecretRestUrl)
                     + "&"
                     + encodeURIComponent(paramsStr);
    
    // again there is no need for an access token, but we need an '&' according to the instructions
    sharedSecret += "&";
    
    var hashedBaseStr  = crypto.createHmac('sha1', sharedSecret).update(sigBaseStr).digest('base64');
    
    // Add oauth_signature to the request object
    reqObj.oauth_signature = hashedBaseStr;
    
    rest.post(fatSecretRestUrl, {
      data: reqObj,
    }).on('complete', function(data, response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("DATA: " + data + "\n");
    });
```

really sorry to anyone using Angular or JQuery, if I ever have a spare minute or two I will try it with angular, also anyone using angular if you get CORS related errors just start chrome like this:

`chromium-browser --disable-web-security` - I do this on terminal
or add that extension to some chrome shortcut on windows, just as a quick work around, hope it helps anybody out there.