# Achieving OAuth 1.0 Authorization in Jmeter latest v5.4.3

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to do a API testing for my legacy application which is using OAuth 1.0 for authorization. Basically I will get a temporary tokens to get a access token for the API testing.

I am using JMeter 5.4.3 for the testing.

In the HTTP Header Manager, I am adding below header
`OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${BbTSConsumerKey}",oauth_consumer_secret="${BbTSConsumerSecret}", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1654865360",oauth_nonce="5348516",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="04Lp%2BF9wZjrFSCjfL%2FLdCepsUYc%3D"`

But above line is not working. Getting 401 - Not Authorized error.

Please help how to make Jmeter work with OAuth v1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add the parameters to the HTTP Header Manager, my expectation is that the values should go to the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler parameters

Moreover:

- `timestamp` should be a number of seconds since the beginning of Unix epoch, i.e. `${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) as int,)}`
- `nonce` should be random, i.e. `${__Random(1111111,9999999,)}`
- `oauth_signature` needs to be [calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910178/calculating-an-oauth-signature), not hard-coded, the most appropriate test element I can think of is [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)
- [Creating a signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature)